# Downlad livros em portugues gutenbergr

Tags: r, tidyverse

Estou tentando baixar livros do projeto Gutemberg usando o pacote "gutenbergr". Uso o seguinte comando:

```
teste <- gutenberg_download(c(40409,    31971, 17515, 42942),
                              meta_fields = "title")
```

O download dos livros ocorre normalmente, mas os caracteres vem todos bacunçados, em especial os acentos. A imagem abaixo traz uma mostra. Há como consertar isso ou é melhor eu baixar um por um e juntar? Valeu!

[image: Erro de caracteres]

Comment: isso é problema de `Encoding` ou `FileEnconding`. qual é o sistema operacional que você está usando?

Comment: Estou Usando MacOS, totalmente em inglês

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é um problema de [codificação de caracteres](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_caracteres). O Projeto Gutenberg usa `latin1`, mas o `R` pensa que é `UTF-8` e aí dá este erro. A parte boa é que ele é facilmente solucionável: basta converter de uma codificação para outra, pois nenhuma informação é perdida. Uma maneira de fazer isso é com a função `iconv` do `R` padrão. Ela é super simples de usar: basta colocar a codificação original e ver qual é a final:

```
library(gutenbergr)
library(dplyr)

teste <- gutenberg_download(c(40409, 31971, 17515, 42942),
                            meta_fields = "title")

teste %>% 
  mutate(text=iconv(text, from = "latin1", to = "UTF-8"))

## # A tibble: 74,057 x 3
##    gutenberg_id text                                                      title   
##           <int> <chr>                                                     <chr>   
##  1        17515 A RELIQUIA                                                A Relíq…
##  2        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  3        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  4        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  5        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  6        17515 *A Reliquia*                                              A Relíq…
##  7        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  8        17515 ""                                                        A Relíq…
##  9        17515 Decidi compôr, nos vagares d'este verão, na minha quinta… A Relíq…
## 10        17515 (antigo solar dos condes de Landoso) as memorias da minh… A Relíq…
## # … with 74,047 more rows
```

Vale notar que rodei este código em um computador que está todo em inglês, rodando o `R` em inglês e com codificação UTF-8. Talvez a tua configuração seja diferente e seja necessário alterar os argumentos utilizados no código acima. De toda forma, caso não dê certo o que coloquei acima, rode o comando `sessionInfo()` no teu PC, compare o resultado com o que obtive abaixo e tente alterar os parâmetros da função `iconv` para obter o resultado desejado.

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
## Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.3
## 
## Matrix products: default
## BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
## LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
## 
## locale:
## [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] dplyr_0.8.0.1    gutenbergr_0.1.4
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 compiler_3.5.2   magrittr_1.5     assertthat_0.2.0 R6_2.4.0        
##  [6] pillar_1.3.1     glue_1.3.0       tibble_2.0.1     crayon_1.3.4     Rcpp_1.0.0      
## [11] pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.3.1      purrr_0.3.0
```

Comment: Muito muto muito obrigado! Eu tbm rodo em MacOs em um computador totalmente em inglês!Sua resposta ajudou muito!